# ¿Como sumar los numeros de una pila?

Tags: java

Buenos dias tego una duda de como puedo sumar los primeros 4 elementos de una pila lo que debo hacer es lo siguiente.

Escribir un procedimiento junta (P: pila; m: integer); que reemplaza los primeros m elementos
de la pila P por su suma. Si hay menos de m elementos en P entonces debe reemplazar todos por su suma. Por
ejemplo, si P= {1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2}, entonces junta (P, 4) debe dejar P= {11, 4, 3, 2}

pero la verdad no tengo idea de como sumar los
ya tengo lo principal que es la clase nodo y la clase pila

alguna idea de como lo puedo solucionar ? gracias de ante mano

```
public class Pila {
    
    private NodoPila cima;

    public Pila() {
    }
    
     public void apilar(int dato) {

        NodoPila aux;
        aux = new NodoPila(dato, cima);
        cima = aux;
    }

    public int desapilar() {

        int x = 0;
        if (cima != null) {
            x = cima.getInformacion();
            cima = cima.getSiguente();
        } else {
            System.out.println("no hay pila");
        }

        return x;
    }
 
    public void Reemplazar(Pila p, int dato){


    }



 
}
```

Comment: desapilas elementos hasta el que necesitas, sumandolos... desapilas el resto.. volves a apilar... cual seria el problema de intentar eso?

Comment: pero como hago para desapilar no mas 4 elementos @gbianchi

Comment: es una pila... si escribis un for de 1 a 4 desapilando, cuantos estarias desapilando?